# Possessive of "day" for "day's leave"

Tags: word-usage, possessives

I need to request leave for one day and for more than one day.

What's the correct way of using the word *day*?

Which is correct for a single day of leave?

> - 1 day's leave
> - 1 day leave

What about more than one day?

> - 2 day's leave
> - 2 days' leave

Please clarify with explanation.

Comment: It's an ordinary possessive, as explained [in this previous question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145071/what-does-days-mean), so it's *one day's* and *two days'*.

Comment: How about using "a two-day leave"?

Comment: ... Not if you wish to say 'I have two days' leave left this year'.

Comment: Or you could say *I have two leave days left this year.*

Comment: Or "two days of leave".  The possessive implies "two days' *worth* of leave", which may be correct if your leave is hourly, and the number of hours correlates to two days of work (ie, 16 hours correlates to two 8-hour workdays).  But that might be overthinking it...

Comment: leave for a day, leave for two days, etc sounds odd?